# How to login to website which is detecting bot usage using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login to the popular clothes reselling platform, 'Depop', using selenium webdriver in Python. When I send my login credentials using Selenium I get the error message "we couldn't verify that you're not a robot" which I cannot get past. I'm open to any ideas (Selenium or otherwise) that will result in me being logged in and allowing me to further navigate Depop pages using Selenium.

Current script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https://www.depop.com/login/")

accept_cookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/button[2]')
accept_cookies.click()

username_input = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
password_input = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
username_input.send_keys('my_username')
password_input.send_keys('my_password')
password_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Screenshot of error message:

[image]

Comment: That looks interesting, thanks. I'll try it out later and lock this as the approved answer if it works. In the meantime, I'm interested to learn of other methods also.

Comment: It was not an answer, only a comment. You can not accept it. Also, your question is already closed as a duplicate, I'm sorry